# How to get Cryptocurrency Candlestick Market Data from Binance in R?

Tags: r, get, finance, binance, cryptocurrency

I had been trying to get **cryptocurrency market data** for some time, and the truth is that it took me a long time to find a way to import them in a clear way in R.

After researching, I think I found a fairly easy way to do it for those of us who use this language and would like to share it. thus, the next person with the same problem won't have to deal with as much.
I also think it would be good if others share their way of doing it, if there is an easier or faster way it would help to us who use R.

For this task we have to use Binance **API**, see the documentation and how to obtain other market data [here](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **GET** the candlestick data we can use the function `fromJSON` from the package `RJSONIO`.

suppose that we want to see the pair **BTC/USDT** in intervals of **1 hour**, the maximum amount of observations that we can adquire in one request is **1000**, so we do:

`Candlestick.data <- fromJSON("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1h&limit=1000")`

seeing the data with `View(Candlestick.data)` we can se that is a `list` of lists, where each sublist contain all the candlestick data corresponding to 1-hour interval (close price, highest price, volume, number of trades, etc.).

To change the lists into a dataframe we could do:

```
i <- 1:length(Candlestick.data)
df <- sapply(i, function(i){as.numeric(unlist(Candlestick.data[i]))})
```

By doing this, each column of `df` corresponds to the **period** (1-hour ago, 2-hours ago, and so on) and each row to the different **candlestick data**. So let's say we want to see all the **close prices** of the last 1000 hours, as we can see in the [documentation](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#klinecandlestick-data) , this is the **5th** element of each list, so we can do this by `df[5,]`.

If we want the rows to be the periods and the columns to be the candlestick data, we can transpose the matrix with `t()` like this
`df_t <- t(df)` and now to get the close prices `df_t[,5]`.

Finally, to make the request easier, we can use the function `paste0()` and now, in summary, we could do for example:

```
library(RJSONIO)

crypto_A <- "ETH"       # the spot market crypto_A vs crypto_B must exist in Binance 
crypto_B <- "BTC"
interval <- "15m"       # see all the possible intervals in the documentation
observations <- "1000"  # remember that the maximum is 1000

Candlestick.data <- fromJSON(paste0("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=",crypto_A,crypto_B,"&interval=",interval,"&limit=",observations))

i <- 1:length(Candlestick.data)
df <- sapply(i, function(i){as.numeric(unlist(Candlestick.data[i]))})

df_t <- t(df)
```

Hope this can help  and remember to read the [documentation](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been getting some traction, so I would like to provide an answer using existing `R` packages that are available.

One of such is the `cryptoQuotes`, which extracts `OHLC` data from Binance using high level functions.

```r
## 1) get BTCUSDT pair 
## from Binance spot market
## for 15m intervals
btc <- cryptoQuotes::getQuote(
  ticker   = 'BTCUSDT',
  interval = '15m',
  source   = 'binance',
  futures  = FALSE
)
```

The `btc` can passed into all the relevant functions in `quantmod` and `TTR`. Below is an example with a candlestick chart with MACD and Bollinger Bands.

```r
## 1) chart using
## quantmod
quantmod::chartSeries(
  x =    tail(btc, 100),
  name = 'BTCUSDT',
  theme = quantmod::chartTheme('white')
)

## 2) add MACD
## and Bollinger BAnds
quantmod::addMACD()
quantmod::addBBands()
```

[image: A candlestick chart with MACD and Bollinger Bands using Quantmod and TTR.]

The package can be installed via `CRAN` as follows,

```r
## install package
install.packages('cryptoQuotes')
```